# Why programmatic navigation of NavigationStack inside a NavigationSplitView doesn't work without a delay?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-navigationsplitview

Here is the simplified version of my app, consisting of `NavigationSplitView` with `NavigationStack` as its detail view.

The programmatic navigation I use here **works** because I delay assignment of the `NavigationStack` path by a second.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var folders: [Folder]

    @State private var currentFolder: Folder?
    @State private var currentPath: [Item] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $currentFolder) {
                ForEach(folders) { folder in
                    NavigationLink(value: folder) {
                        Text(folder.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $currentPath) {
                if let currentFolder = currentFolder {
                    List(currentFolder.items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(value: item) {
                            Text(item.timestamp.ISO8601Format())
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
                        Text(item.title)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onOpenURL(perform: { url in // Triggers by clicking on a widget
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Folder>()
            // Randomly selecting a folder
            // In real app the url contains the folder and the item
            let folder = try? modelContext.fetch(descriptor).last

            if let folder = folder {
                currentFolder = folder // Triggering NavigationSplitView navigation

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { // After one second
                    currentPath = [folder.items.last!] // Triggering NavigationStack navigation
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private func addFolder() {
    // ..
    }
}
```

If I won't delay the `currentPath` assignment, it will only navigate the `NavigationSplitView`. If the app is in the background and it is already in the correct folder in `NavigationSplitView` it will navigate to the item in the `NavigationStack`.

In the apple video (https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10054) they do just the assignment without any delay and it works:

```
// This code work in Apple sample video
currentFolder = folder
currentPath = [folder.items.last!]
```

Why doesn't it work for me without a delay?

Comment: maybe your `if let` without an `else` View has broken it? Try `List(currentFolder?.items ?? [])` instead

Comment: @malhal no effect, still doesn't work. 

From what I investigated, it seems that SwiftUI doesn't have the NavigationStack being ready to react to the path change if you assign both bindigs at the same time.

Another confirmation of this is the fact what it does navigate the NavigationStack if the NavigationSplitView is already in the correct folder thus having NavigationStack prepared to react to the path change.

Comment: ok next guess is maybe because you didn't read `currentPath` anywhere in the top level of `body`. Try `} detail: { [currentPath] in` as workaround.

Comment: Actually try that for `currentFolder` instead. Also, you should probably move the detail to a sub View since you don't need the `@State currentPath` in this one. You can have 2 onOpenURLs defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work consistently, visually attractive and for any platform (iOS, macOS and iPadOS). Here is how to properly assign bindings:

```
// ...

var nonAnimatedTransaction: Transaction {
  var t = Transaction()
  t.disablesAnimations = true

  return t
}

// ...
}.onOpenURL(perform: { url
  // ...
  if let folder = folder {
    withTransaction(nonAnimatedTransaction) {
      currentFolder = folder // Triggers NavigationSplitView without animation
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       currentPath = [folder.items.last!] // Triggers NavigationStack navigation
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Removing animation for the `NavigationSplitView` and updating the path inside the main thread solved the issue.

Having default transition animation (which takes time) prevented the `NavigationStack` to be ready for the path change and updating the path inside the main thread is the correct way to update binding because the `onOpenURL` is an async task which runs in a separate thread and all UI related changes should be done in the main thread.

So this is the way to navigate to the proper path after a click on an app widget. You don't want to see long lasting animations, only the last one.